# Are there additional requirements to get the sender info on a Facebook messenger optin event?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm listening to the [optin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference/optins) event fired by Facebook Messenger. The docs say I should receive an object with `{ 'sender': { 'id': 'USER_ID' } }` in it. However, the data I get is missing this information. I do receive the optin event, and I get the rest of the data, but I'm missing the `sender`.

The response I get looks like this:

```
"messaging"=>[{
    "recipient"=>{"id"=>"MY_PAGE_ID"},
    "timestamp"=>1503480281655,
    "optin"=>{"ref"=>"PASS_THROUGH_PARAM", "user_ref"=>"5019"}
}]
```

I'm using the [facebook-messenger](https://github.com/jgorset/facebook-messenger/) gem to handle the webhook events. However I decided to intercept the request directly to check the data I was getting, which is what I used to generate the above response. The object the gem gives me looks like this:

```
#<Facebook::Messenger::Incoming::Optin:0x007fe2829a4928
    @messaging={ "recipient"=>{"id"=>"MY_PAGE_ID"},
                 "timestamp"=>1503480091027, 
                 "optin"=>{"ref"=>"PASS_THROUGH_PARAM", "user_ref"=>"58326"}
                }>
```

Here's where I [listen](https://github.com/lbain/rise/blob/master/app/bot/listen.rb#L14-L18) to the optin event.

Finally the click handler to fire the optin event is exactly per Facebook's documentation:

```
  FB.AppEvents.logEvent('MessengerCheckboxUserConfirmation', null, {
    'app_id':'<%= Figaro.env.facebook_app_id %>',
    'page_id':'<%= Figaro.env.facebook_page_id %>',
    'ref':'PASS_THROUGH_PARAM',
    'user_ref':'<%= @uniq_user_ref %>'
  });
```

Here's the rest of that [file](https://github.com/lbain/rise/blob/master/app/views/pages/index.html.erb#L20-L27) in case it's valuable.

Is there anything else I need to set up or pass through to tell Facebook I want this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible you're using the [Checkbox](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/plugin-reference/checkbox-plugin) plugin instead of the [Send to Messenger](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/plugin-reference/send-to-messenger) plugin? On the Checkbox documentation, they mention the following (emphasis mine):

> **Callback**
>
> After the opt-in event, we will post a webhook event to your server if
> the checkbox state was checked. *This callback has the same format as
> the opt-in callback, but instead of a sender field, it has an optin
> object with a user_ref field.*

Comment: Dop! Thank you! I thought they were the same event, and hadn't realised using the checkbox would result in different data.